# What is the name of this slender slab / sans hybrid typeface?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif, slab-serif

I want to use the **font shown in the image** below in my Android Apllication.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to know the name of this font. Does anyone know which font is this? I searched on What The Font site but I don't find any related font.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information. What application is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Flamenco](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Flamenco), a Google font. At the link, you can find instructions on how to use it and information about the font's license—which basically allows you to do nigh everything with it.

[image]